# Why am I getting this error message: "'IMediaManager' does not contain a definition for 'MediaExtractor'" with xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, android, ios, video, xamarin.forms

I am developing an app that can also Livestream Video, but I am having some issues.

I have downloaded and installed Plugin.MediaManager.Forms (and also Plugin.MediaManager) via Nuget. I have also done the needful as you can see below:

In MainActivity.cs (I am referencing MediaManager & I also Initialized CrossMediaManager)

```
    using Android.App;
    using Android.Content.PM;
    using Android.Runtime;
    using Android.OS;
    using MediaManager;
    namespace Abuse_Alert.Droid
    {
       [Activity(Label = "Abuse_Alert", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]

   public class MainActivity : 
   global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
   {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Init(this);

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
   }
    }
```

The XAml File looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"

         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="AbuseAlert.Views.Page1"
         xmlns:mm="clr-namespace:MediaManager.Forms;assembly=MediaManager.Forms"
         x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">

<ContentPage.Content>
<mm:VideoView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              BackgroundColor="Black"
              x:Name="mmVideoView"
              />
</ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

In the code behind, this is what I have done:

```
    if (isHLS)
    {
      var item2 = await CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaExtractor.CreateMediaItem(URL);

      item2.MediaType = MediaManager.Media.MediaType.Hls;
      CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaPlayer.VideoView.ShowControls = false;

      await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(item2);
   }
   else
   {
      await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(URL);
   }
```

Nevertheless, these are the error messages I am getting in 3 above:

1. The name 'isHLS' does not exist in the current context
2. 'IMediaManager' does not contain a definition for 'MediaExtractor' and no accessible
   extension method 'MediaExtractor' accepting a first argument of type 'IMediaManager'
   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3. The type or namespace name 'MediaType' does not exist in the namespace
   'MediaManager.Media' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
4. 'IVideoView' does not contain a definition for 'ShowControls' and no accessible
   extension method 'ShowControls' accepting a first argument of type 'IVideoView' could
   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So, what am I supposed to have done that I have not done? I am using VS 2022 with xamarin.forms.

Comment: to start with, where are you declaring `isHLS`?

Comment: Ok, isHLS wasn't defined anywhere. But, I have now defined it as 
public bool isHLS = false;
Now the error "The name 'isHLS' does not exist in the current context" has disappeared.

An issue that would arise is how do I determine that the livestream is HLS so I can assign
to the isHLS boolean variable before I start livestreaming?

Comment: do you have all the necessary `using` statements?  `MediaType` is in namespace `MediaManager.Library`

Comment: I believe so. I have referenced or used MediaManager in the Android MainActivity.cs & also in the Itemsviewmodel.cs (where I am invoking CrossMediaManager from). Is there any declaration I need to do so that the MediaType error will disappear? When I looked at "MediaManager.Media.", Mediatype is not among the entities that appear.

Comment: do you have `using MediaManager.Library;` in your using statements or not?  VS will help you fix these errors if you hover over them and select "Suggested Fix" from the context menu

Comment: I tried "using MediaManager.Library;" and the suggested fixes complained that it was unnecessary but it is accepting "using MediaManager;"

Comment: `MediaManager.Media.MediaType.Hls;` should be `MediaManager.Library.MediaType.Hls;`, or just remover the namespace and use the `using` statement instead

Comment: MediaManager.Library.MediaType.HLs has worked. Thanks.

Comment: What about the CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaExtractor.CreateMediaItem(URL)? It is complaining about the Mediaextractor.

Comment: the name of the property is `Extractor`.  See https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager/blob/0c71adec50118cfbb521b60e7a8955baf5c3f110/MediaManager/IMediaManager.cs#L36

Comment: Great. I used await CrossMediaManager.Current.Extractor.CreateMediaItem(URL) and the error has cleared.

Comment: I am still having error with the Showcontrols. This is how I created the VideoView.xaml file:    <ContentPage.Content>
    <mm:VideoView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  BackgroundColor="Black"
                  x:Name="mmVideoView"
                  />
    </ContentPage.Content>. I can't see any controls there.

Comment: `mmVideoView.ShowControls = true;`

Comment: Another issue has now come up when I am trying to run the project. "Java.exe" exit with error code 1. Other people complained about Proguard but I don't have it installed. Maybe, it is because I updated the Java on my system today. If that's the cause, how do i update the Java components of my project?

Comment: this sounds like a completely unrelated issue to your original question

Comment: I know. I have reverted back to the backup copy I made before attempting this feature update. Everything is ok again. I will now try it out again and be able to find out (or not) what could be causing the Java.exe issue. Thanks.